# Where is the satellite receiver/control for 2010 Mercury Milan?

Tags: audio, mercury, milan

My 2010 Mercury Milan is Sirius radio capable. I accepted a free trial but can not get the radio to work. All that is displayed is `No Signal`.

I've called Sirius who graciously walked me through some troubleshooting. To verify the radio ID I was told to hold the <kbd>Sirius</kbd> and the <kbd>1</kbd> simultaneously. This did not work. No ID was displayed.

The Sirius tech told me to check the connections to the control unit, but I can not find it. I'm trying to avoid a trip to the dealer. Does anyone know where it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed the radio from the car and was able to finally determine the satellite control is integrated into the radio unit. On the unit itself is a tag with the ID #.

Unfortunately, once all connections were reseated, I still have the same problem.